# How to Install google-talkplugin deb in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: deb, 16.04, google-hangouts

I need to install this plugin in Ubuntu 16.04:

https://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/hangoutplugin

In previous versions of Ubuntu, I easily installed this plugin, but I cannot get it to install on 16.04 with its new GUI software manager.

I've submitted a bug about this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1573408

Please suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to install the plug-in using the command line like this:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-talkplugin_current_amd64.deb
```

That produced this:

```
Selecting previously unselected package google-talkplugin.
(Reading database ... 196768 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack google-talkplugin_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-talkplugin (5.41.0.0-1) ...
Setting up google-talkplugin (5.41.0.0-1) ...
```

After this, I restarted Firefox. I went to Gmail to make a phone call, and after clicking the "Allow" button (prompted at the top of Firefox -- under the address bar), it worked.

However, after installing this, I was no longer able to sudo apt-get update

```
sudo apt-get update
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key ***************omitted****************** uses weak digest
algorithm (SHA1)
E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/Release  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_Release which is considered strong enough for security purposes
```

For now, I've disabled that repository by un-checking this:

[image]

The above step is my weak workaround for this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1562733

Someone told me that I could just ignore that error until the repository is fixed (instead of disabling it, like above). However, I did not find this to be the case; it seems that if there is one failure during a sudo apt-get update, succeeding repositories (after that error -- ones without issues) do not get hit (therefore it ultimately blocks your ability to fully update your computer).

If I understand the bug correctly, it seems like Google will need to fix their repository to adhere to Debian/Ubuntu's (new) higher security requirements for signing packages.

To encourage Google to fix this, see here:
https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Apt/Sha1Removal

Comment: How do you install this plugin in a manner where it will receive updates from from the Google repository in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: That debian wiki page leads to a JVApen post from 17 June 2016 indicating that the bug is fixed; and only the cache needs cleaned. But it still doesn't work for me. See https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/oqnwWyiAvWg/9hgjmdF_BgAJ

Answer (score 0):

After updating gnome-software / ubuntu-software:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-software
```

I could install the 64 bit .deb from Google without problems.

Comment: That is because they fixed this bug since April 2016 (when the question was submitted).